# Using cgroup & tc in linux seems to NOT apply exactly my rates: 10x discrepancy

Tags: tc, cgroup

I'm using the "standard" way that I found everywhere on the internet (including ServerFault) to try and limit the bandwidth of a process, using cgroups & tc.

What I see in practice is that the limits I set through `tc` will be about 10 times more in practice, see this screenshot:

[image]

I set `rate` and `ceil` to 100kbit (NOT 100kbps), so I expect to see my wget below to show about 10 kilobytes per second. Instead I see 500kBps.

If I update my htp rate to 100**kbps** (100 kilobytes per second) I see my rate shoot up to 10 **Megabytes/second**, which is 100 times more:

```bash
tc class change dev ens3 classid 1:1 htb rate 100kbps

# the curl in the other terminal now shoots up to 9.6MB/s
image.iso.1    53%[================>                ] 346,72M  **9,48MB/s**    tps 49s
```

I don't understand why this is not coherent with my htb configuration. Do you have any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With tc, you are shaping the upload speed. With wget, you are testing the download speed. In your test, you are the shaping the TCP ACK sent by your client, so we can conclude that the ratio data / ack is 1:100 in your case.

You can shape the download speed by redirecting with tc the ingress flows to an ifb interface and shaping on it. [Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/advanced_traffic_control#Example_of_ingress_traffic_shaping_with_SNAT) you have an example on how to do it.